# Como definir dados que vão ser mostrados no gridView

Tags: c#, gridview

Tenho está classe usuarioDAO, onde faço um select para retornar apenas: Matricula, Nome e Acessos e retornar em um gridView.

```
public List<Usuario> ObterTotalporMatricula()
    {
        var lista = new List<Usuario>();

        using (var connection = ServiceLocator.ObterConexao())
        {
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT MATRICULA,NOME,ACESSOS FROM USUARIO";

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var todos = PreenchePropriedade(reader);
                    lista.Add(todos);
                }
            }
            return lista;
        }

    }

    private Usuario PreenchePropriedade(OleDbDataReader reader)
    {
        var todos = new Usuario();

        todos.Matricula = reader.GetString(0);
        todos.Nome = reader.GetString(1);
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
        {
            todos.Acessos = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2));
        }

        return todos;
    }

}
```

O problema que estou tendo é que no meu gridView está retornando todos atributos de uma entidade usuario que eu tenho em meu projeto. Minha dúvida é como faço para retornar apenas estes 3 dados no meu gridView ??

```
private void ObterTotalPorMatricula()
    {
        var usuarioController = new UsuarioController();
        var lista = usuarioController.ObterTotalporMatricula();

        this.GridView1.DataSource = lista;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

> O gridVIew está retornando os atributos da minha entidade Usuario + EntidadeBasica

```
public class Usuario : EntidadeBasica
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Matricula { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int NivelAcessoId { get; set; }
    public int ? CodigoMaleta  { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Acessos { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo o que você fez está correto, porém ainda faltam alguns ajustes:

1. Aplique a propriedade `AutoGenerateColumns` do `gridview` para `false`.
2. Crie as colunas no html e aplique os respectivos nomes de propriedades da sua classe usuário aos campos `datafield` das colunas.

Veja um exemplo de como criar as colunas e aplicar o `datafield`no site da [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx).